# start /stop jquery menu

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

when using jgrowl and if we invoke the following to close all the menus

```
 $.jGrowl(data);   
 $.jGrowl('shutdown');
```

How to start it back.

The following gives an error

```
$.jGrowl('startup');
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no error but again on the call of jgrowl ,it just doesnt show up, since we have called shutdown

Comment: K the code goes like this
     func a(){
      $.jGrowl(data);   
      }

     func cleanup(){
     $.jGrowl('shutdown');
     }
     a();
     cleanup();
So again if `a()` is called with or without `$.jGrowl('startup');`

the jgrowl doesnt show up

Answer (score 0):

Startup ought to be a valid option:

http://bitbucket.org/stanlemon/jgrowl/src/47d58d0e497f/jquery.jgrowl.js

Code snippet from this page:

```
    /** Setup the jGrowl Notification Container **/
    startup:    function(e) {
        this.element = $(e).addClass('jGrowl').append('<div class="jGrowl-notification"></div>');
        this.interval = setInterval( function() { 
            $(e).data('jGrowl.instance').update(); 
        }, this.defaults.check);

        if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version) < 7 && !window["XMLHttpRequest"]) {
            $(this.element).addClass('ie6');
        }
    },
```

Can you supply details of the error, and maybe some more code to help us determine what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Hi James,There is no error but again on the call of jgrowl ,it just doesnt show up, since we have called shutdown.Any ideas y?

Comment: Here is a hint of code.

The code goes like this
     func a(){
      $.jGrowl(data);   
      }

     func cleanup(){
     $.jGrowl('shutdown');
     }
     a();
     cleanup();
So again if `a()` is called with or without `$.jGrowl('startup');`

the jgrowl doesnt show up